# How to identify/print the key with the greatest value in a dictonary?

Tags: python, dictionary, key

I've found some similar questions but none has solved my problem. Follow this example:

```
d={'a': 6, 'b': 3, 'c': 8, 'd': 1}
```

Now I wanna print the key that has the greatest number (in this case `'c'`) and the smallest too (in this case `'d'`). Realize that what I wanna print is the key, not its value.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use built-ins [`min()`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html#min)/[`max()`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html#max) with custom `key=` parameter:

```
d={'a': 6, 'b': 3, 'c': 8, 'd': 1}

print('Min key =', min(d, key=lambda k: d[k]) )
print('Max key =', max(d, key=lambda k: d[k]) )
```

Prints:

```
Min key = d
Max key = c
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. But is there a way without using lambda functions? I haven't learned it yet in my algorithm class, so I'm not suposed to use it.

Answer (score 1):

@Mateus, here is another way that doesn't use lambda functions:

```
d={'a': 6, 'b': 3, 'c': 8, 'd': 1}

# Solution #1 - Using lambda function
print('Min key =', min(d, key=lambda k: d[k]))
print('Max key =', max(d, key=lambda k: d[k]))

# Solution #2 - Using the dictionary get() method
print ('Min key =', min(d, key=d.get))
print ('Max key =', max(d, key=d.get))
```

Either approach will give the same result:

```
Min key = d
Max key = c
Min key = d
Max key = c
```